# Unwanted decimal in text area

Tags: android

i have the following text area named "results", that holds my result.

Default from xml is: "0"

After calculation from class file shown below, returns ie: "1.0"

I do not want the "." or the "0" just whole numbers, ie "1" "2" "3" etc...

```
protected void addone() {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(results.getText().toString()); 
    results.setText(Double.toString(val+1));
}

protected void minusone() {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(results.getText().toString());
    if (val > 0 ){
    results.setText(Double.toString(val-1));
    }
}

protected void resetit() {
AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(actcountonit.this);
ab.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color=#ff0000> Warning.! " +"</font></b><br>Are you sure you want to reset the counter..?"));
            ab.setPositiveButton("Reset", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        results.setText(Double.toString(0));
                    }
                    });

            ab.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    ab.show();
}
```

I have tried to amend this to get the value from the text area as an int, then return it to text area as an int.
Every combination i have tried, i get error's in these lines.

```
protected void addone() {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(results.getText().toString()); 
    results.setText(Double.toString(val+1));
}
```

An example of a function like this, where your taking the numeric value of a text box as an int, do the calcs then return it as an int "whole number" would be great..!

This amendment of mine shows errors in eclipse at both capitalized "Int"s.

```
protected void addone() {
    int val = Int.parseInt(results.getText().toString()); 
    results.setText(Int.toString(val+1));
}
```

Finally worked it out:

```
protected void addone() {
    int val = Integer.parseInt(results.getText().toString()); 
    results.setText(Integer.toString(val+1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're using doubles rather than ints? It sounds like integers are what you're really wanting to use here.

Comment: i have tried various ways to construct these onclick events in eclipse. but as i am new to android and java, i cant get the correct format.

Comment: Try just using `int` instead of `Double`. Unless you're doing any sort of decimal calculations, there's no reason to use a double here.

Comment: I have tried, i am just not competent enough with the syntax yet. I have amended a note to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Got it...! Showing at end of question above.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't help with the actual code, but glad you figured it out!